# Eclipse not displaying JMenu items after adding to and setting JMenuBar visible?

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem, jmenubar

Not getting any errors however the program only displays the word "menu" at the top in the program. It doesn't display the 3 `JMenu` items: "home", "about" and "explore".

```
JPanel p5 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                p5.setVisible(true);
                fw.add(p5, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

                JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
                menu.setVisible(true);
                menu.add("home");
                menu.add("about");
                menu.add("explore");

                JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
                fw.setJMenuBar(menubar); //ADDED THIS LINE. STILL DOESN'T WORK. 

                menubar.setVisible(true);
                menubar.add(menu);
                p5.add(menu);
```

I've added `JMenu` to `JMenuBar` (everything `JMenu`, `JMenubar` and `JPanel` is set to visible). Also I added JPanel (p5) to "first window (fw) and added menu to p5. I'm not sure why my menu items are not being displayed.

**UPDATE:**  MCVE (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example) as requested.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;  
public class TestingClass  extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FirstWindow fw = new FirstWindow();
        fw.setSize(400, 600);
        fw.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);         
        fw.setVisible(true);

        JPanel p5 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        p5.setVisible(true);

        fw.add(p5);

        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
        menu.setVisible(true);
        menu.add("home");
        menu.add("about");
        menu.add("explore");

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        fw.setJMenuBar(menubar);    // THE UPDATED LINE OF CODE.
        menubar.setVisible(true);
        menubar.add(menu);
        p5.add(menu);
      } 
    }
```

As you run the program, you will see the words "menu" displayed. The items: "home, about and explore" from `JMenu` are not displayed. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've added the MCVE. Can you see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An MCVE of a run-time problem should compile cleanly.  That shows 3 compilation errors.  One is a missing import (easily fixable), but the other two relate to the missing `FirstWindow`.

Nevertheless, once a few tweaks were made, the problem becomes clear.  A component can only appear in one place.  By adding it to the panel as well (commented out below), it cannot appear in the menu.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestingClass  extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame fw = new JFrame();
        fw.setSize(400, 200); // for screenshot
        fw.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel p5 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        p5.setVisible(true);

        fw.add(p5);

        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
        //menu.setVisible(true);
        menu.add("home");
        menu.add("about");
        menu.add("explore");

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        fw.setJMenuBar(menubar);    // THE UPDATED LINE OF CODE.
        //menubar.setVisible(true);
        menubar.add(menu);
        //p5.add(menu); // WTF?

        fw.setVisible(true); //should be done after all components are added
    }
}
```

Comment: Note:  GUIs should be started on the EDT (which I've not changed - BNI).  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your help, very much appreciated. So, what I was doing wrong was adding JMenu to JPanel. While you only have to add JMenu to JMenuBar, not JPanel. This is because by adding a component to the JPanel and JMenuBar it doesn't appear at all. One question if I may ask you: You didn't add JMenuBar to JPanel, rather you added it directly to JFrame (fw.setJMenuBar(menubar) then what is the use of JPanel if we don't directly add components i.e. (JMenuBar) to JPanel?

Comment: *"..then what is the use of JPanel if we don't directly add components i.e. (JMenuBar) to JPanel?"*  IF the GUI does not need any components, none.  But then, how often can we (do we need to) make a GUI with only a menu bar?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the menuBar to the frame:

```
frame.setJMenuBar( menuBar );
```

Also, you don't need do make Swing components visible since they are visible by default (except for top level contains, like JFrame which you do need to set visible).

Comment: After adding fw.setJMenuBar(menuBar); like you said (see the code above); it still doesn't show the menu items from JMenu. In fact, it made no changes in the program.

Comment: @user3289740, Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for a working example. Compare the working example with your code to see what is different. Or better yet, use the working example as a starting point and then customize the code for your requirement, since the working example is probably better structured than your code. We can't give you any more advice because your code is not complete.

Answer (score -2):

You need to call `setVisible(`) after adding component! So first add all components. Add the highest level component to the `JFrame`(`JPanel` in your case) and the only call `setVisible()` for the `JFrame`. No need to call on every component.

```
JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
menu.add("home");
menu.add("about");
menu.add("explore");
//rest of the components
//add panelto the frame
frame.getContentPane.add(p5);
//set menubar for the frame
frame.setJMenuBar( menuBar );
//set visibility for frame to true
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: -1 Swing components are visible by default, except for top level containers

Comment: `JMenu` is visible by default, in fact, all Swing components are visible by default except for windows (include `JInternalFrame`)

Comment: Yeah my point only was to call `setVisible()` after adding all components.All we have to to is set visibility of frame to true or false depending on our wish to show or hide the frame.

Comment: *"Yeah my point only was.."* ..not well expressed in your answer.  An [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24347877/edit) seems in order.

Comment: I didn't remove my down vote because the answer is still misleading. There is no need to add the menu to the menubar before setting the menubar on the frame. The key is to add all the components to the GUI (in whatever order you like) before making the fame visible. Even if you remove that line I will not remove the down vote because I should not need to verify every statement you make.